# Moving rectangle with key listener program for game

Tags: java, keylistener

Hey guys I have been trying to get a rectangle to move with keylistener in Java applet. The only problem with it is the class name for some reason. It says that it is not implemented in the abstract class. Any ideas why?

Here is the error message: The abstract method "void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent $1);", inherited from type "java.awt.event.KeyListener",is not implemented in the non-abstract class "SoccerGame"

```
// The "SoccerGame" class.
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SoccerGame extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    int x = 200, y = 200;


    public void init ()
    {
    this.requestFocus ();
    addKeyListener (this);

    setSize (800, 550);
    } // init method


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
    g.drawRect (20, 20, 340, 340);

    g.fillRect (x,  y, 20, 20);
    } // paint method

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y-10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y+10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x-10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x+10;
    }

    repaint ();
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

} // SoccerGame class
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message.  Exact.  As in, letter for letter.

Comment: sure I'll get the error message.

Comment: The abstract method "void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent $1);", inherited from type "java.awt.event.KeyListener",is not implemented in the non-abstract class "SoccerGame"

Comment: (1-) quit flooding the forum with question on the same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KeyListener` interface that your class is attempting to implement contains one more method, called `keyTyped()`, which your class must also implement.  So, just add an empty implementation of that method.

Documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html